# Dudas en Consultas Preparadas PHP Y SQL, Sentencia SELECT y Mostrar Datos

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, select, prepared-statements

Intento actualizar algunos sistemas que tengo creados, en los que intento añadir `consultas preparadas` para mejorar principalmente la seguridad.

Estoy intentando hacer un `SELECT` y no me queda muy claro como podría recorrerlo.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = ?";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "i", $id_cliente);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
```

He pensado en hacer esto, y hasta aquí he llegado.

- ¿Es una buena forma? o.. ¿Podría hacer la consulta de otra forma mejor?
- ¿Como puedo recorrerla con un while? para mostrar por ejemplo

`row['nombre'];`

Gracias, y disculpad, si para algunos resulta muy básico, pero no había tocado casi nada hasta ahora las `prepared statments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy buenos días te dejo un código para que puedas guiarte:

```
$sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = ?";
$sentencia= mysqli_prepare($sql);
$sentencia->bind_param('i', $idCLiente);
$idCLiente = 12;

$sentencia->execute();  

// Vinculamos variables a campos
$sentencia->bind_result($campo1, $campo2);

// Obtenemos los valores
while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
  printf("%s %s\n", $campo1, $campo2);
}

// Cerramos la sentencia preparada
$sentencia->close();
```

**Explicación:**

**$sql** seria la variable donde indicas tu query o consulta sql, luego llamamos al método **mysqli_prepare** para indicar que es una consulta preparada, posteriormente enlazamos el o los signos de interrogación con la variable o variables que tendrán los filtros para tu query en este caso **$idCliente**, por eso colocamos **bind_param**. Si te fijas hay una **'i'** antes de la variable **$idCliente**, eso es para indicar el tipo de datos, en este caso **int**, si necesitas pasar más filtros quedaria así:

```
$sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = ? AND idOtro = ? AND nombre = ?";
$sentencia= mysqli_prepare($sql);
$sentencia->bind_param('iis', $idCLiente,$idOtro,$nombre);
```

Si te fijas ahora esta **'iis'** que significa que serán dos enteros y un string. Luego indicas los valores de las variables enlazadas.

Luego para recorrer el resultado debes de especificar el valor de los campos obtenidos para eso usamos el **bind_result** donde almacenaremos los valores de dichos campos en unas variables y después puedes recorrerlo con un **while**.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola David, gracias por tu comentario, pero lo que necesito son consultas preparadas.

Comment: Ok disculpa ya lo edite, ve a ver si te sirve

Comment: las respuestas no solo deben ser código si no también explicación; de lo contrario se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: Listo ya agregue una breve explicación espero me sepa entender.